# Node express: 404 on some routes but not others

Tags: node.js, express, routes

So I have a problem where some of my express.js (v3.2.0) routes are returning a 404 status code, while others are not.  I can't figure out why some routes are working fine while other ones aren't resolving.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

server.js:

```
//npm packages
var express = require('express')
  , app = express()
  , server = require('http').createServer(app)
  ;
if(process.env.NODE_ENV == 'production') require('newrelic');

//local resources
init = require('./lib/init');
ctrl = require('./lib/ctrl')

//external async resources (global variables)
init.setup(function(){

  //configure express
  _util.configExpress(__dirname, app, express);

  // create a new AI classifier
  //
  // Arguments
  // ---------
  //    modelType   - (path param) ID of the classifier
  //    modelParams - (body) JSON containing to configure the model
  //
  // Returns
  // -------
  //    200 - ID of created classifier
  //    400 - Error during creation
  app.get('/clf/create/:modelType', _util.auth(express.basicAuth), function(req, res) {
    var modelParams = req.body ? req.body : {};
    var modelType = req.params.modelType;
    ctrl.clfCreate(modelType, modelParams, function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        // at this point, assume bad request
        res.status(400);
        res.json({"err": err.message});
      } else {
        // if success, return classifier ID
        res.json({"id": result});
      }
      res.end();
    });
  });

  // [Unrelated endpoints...]

  //handle resource update data from io server
  app.all('/:clientId/:projectId/train', _util.auth(express.basicAuth), function (req, res){
    ctrl.trainer(req.params.clientId, req.params.projectId, function(err, result){/*res.json(result);*/});
    res.end();
  });

  // [Unrelated endpoints...]

  //listen on app port
  var port;
  var expr = _env.name == 'prod' ? port = process.env.PORT : port = _env.app.ai.port;
  server.listen(port);
  console.log('Listening to: '+port);
});
```

_util.configExpress:

```
self.configExpress = function(dirname, app, express){                                                                                                                                                                                        
  app.configure(function() {                                                                                             
    //setup jade                                                                                                         
    app.set('views', dirname+'/views')                                                                                   
    app.set('view engine', 'jade')                                                                                       
    //setup friendly console logging                                                                                     
    app.use(express.logger('dev'))                                                                                       
    //use body parser for handling http post                                                                             
    app.use(express.bodyParser());                                                                                       
    //define static file server                                                                                          
    app.use(express.static(dirname+'/'+_env.assets));                                                                    
  });                                                                                                                    
}
```

But then when I test the endpoints:

```
$ curl -vv --user bst:bst localhost:3002/clf/create/bnn
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3002 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'bst'
> GET /clf/create/bnn HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3002
> Authorization: Basic YnN0OmJzdA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Content-Type: text/plain
< Content-Length: 9
< Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 18:54:32 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
Not Found%  

$ -vv --user bst:bst localhost:3002/bst/drone/train
*   Trying ::1...
* Connected to localhost (::1) port 3002 (#0)
* Server auth using Basic with user 'bst'
> GET /bst/drone/train HTTP/1.1
> Host: localhost:3002
> Authorization: Basic YnN0OmJzdA==
> User-Agent: curl/7.43.0
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< X-Powered-By: Express
< Date: Thu, 02 Jul 2015 18:54:45 GMT
< Connection: keep-alive
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
➜  reporting git:(feature/ai-train-api) ✗
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using express version 3, you are trying to user route params like version 4.

`req.params` is an array not an object in version 3

Try looking [here](https://github.com/strongloop/express/wiki/Migrating-from-3.x-to-4.x#reqparams).

### Code example

Try this I imagine that because `var modelType` would have been undefined that your ctrl,clfCreate() function failed to ever send the response.  In the other endpoint you have `res.end()` outside the scope of your ctrl function

```
app.get('/clf/create/:modelType', _util.auth(express.basicAuth), function(req, res) {
    var modelParams = req.body ? req.body : {};
    var modelType = req.params[0];
    ctrl.clfCreate(modelType, modelParams, function(err, result) {
      if(err) {
        // at this point, assume bad request
        res.status(400);
        res.json({"err": err.message});
      } else {
        // if success, return classifier ID
        res.json({"id": result});
      }
      res.end();
    });
  });
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this didn't resolve the issue.  I was using the v4 style by convention, as another dev on the team wrote the original file and used it successfully.  I don't deign to know what black magic allowed this, but if you see the code I posted, the function that runs successfully also accesses req.params in this way.  **edit:**  the problem persists even when I alter the 2nd endpoint to have `res.end()` within the inner callback.

Comment: Alright I see, glad you could test it. Ill take another look and see if I can find the issue. Have you tried just sending a string response to test? `res.send('success');`?

Comment: Try using app.all() on /clf/create/:modelType instead of get()?

Comment: Unfortunately no luck on either count.  Even with this http://pastebin.com/dCswM1Qq .  It looks like this is purely a routing issue...

Comment: Marking this as the answer, since the solution ended up being upgrading to express v4.  Maybe it was an old bug on their side.

Comment: Well glad to see you fixed it!